# How should we guide the growth of the "tag universe"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I understand there was a question before about merging tags, but what about the overall evolution of the universe of tags?

There have been several questions in meta regarding how we handle "homework" questions and technical question et al...what about how we label those questions in the first place?

What if we agreed on a set of tags that should absolutely be included in the site- should we go ahead and create them so they show up as suggestions once we go live?  That way the merge issue isn't quite as relevant?

How would we do that, if at all?

Answer (score 2):

On other new stack exchange sites, it's been best to let the tag universe grow fairly organically, tracking the expansion in number and range of questions, and defined by the askers and the editors. That is, the ontology is an emergent property of the actual question set.

And we use meta for discussions about specific tags, once there's a sufficient number of questions using the tag(s), to discuss.

I don't think this site is different, in this regard.